# Error de compilación al usar "pow" en C

Tags: c, gcc

Tengo un problema al compilar este código. Me dieron la solución pero para ser honesto no sé a qué se debió la falla ya que he visto programas parecidos al mío y los compilo normalmente con `gcc -o XXXXX XXXXX.c` y no dan ese problema.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

#define PI 3.14159

/* Compular el programa con el atributo -O2 
 * gcc -O2 -o fig02_20 fig02_20.c para que no 
 * de el error de compilación */
/* inicio de la ejecucion del programa con la funcion main */
int main(void)
{
    system("clear");

    float area,
          circunferencia,
          diametro,
          radio;

    printf("Introduzca el radio: ");
    scanf("%f", &radio);

    diametro = radio * 2;
    circunferencia = diametro * PI;
    area = PI * pow(radio, 2);

    printf("El diametro es de %f. \n", diametro);
    printf("La circunferencia es de %f. \n", circunferencia);
    printf("El area es de %f. \n", area);

    return 0; /* finalizacion del programa con exito */

}   /* fin de la funcion main */
```

Al compilar el código con `gcc -o fig02_20 fig02_20.c` me envía el siguiente mensaje:

> /tmp/ccjNruco.o: En la función `main`:
> fig02_20.c:(.text+0x90): referencia a `pow` sin definir
> collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

¿Qué quiere decir? Gracias.

Comment: casi nunca deberías usar `pow`.  `radio * radio` hace lo mismo.

Comment: Hola plazamarco. ¿Mi respuesta aclaró tu pregunta? Si es así agradecería que la marcaras como correcta. En caso contrario agradecería que me dejaras un comentario en ella con las dudas que tengas.

Answer (score 6):

Ese mensaje te aparece porque por defecto no se enlaza la biblioteca de funciones matemáticas al generar el ejecutable final. Sin embargo, si sólo compilas tu código, no te dará error alguno (aunque te lo dará de nuevo más adelante cuando quieras generar el ejecutable final).

Para solucionarlo debes enlazar, de manera explícita, la biblioteca de funciones matemáticas, que se llama `m`:

```
gcc -o fig02_20 fig02_20.c -lm
```

De manera general, el parámetro `-l` va inmediatamente precedido por el nombre de la biblioteca de funciones que quieras enlazar. Usando `-lm` estás solicitando enlazar la biblioteca cuyo nombre es `m`.

El nombre de archivo que se buscará para ser enlazado será `libm.so` (objeto compartido) o `libm.a` (archivo estático). En Ubuntu, por ejemplo, ambos están localizados en `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/`.

---

**Nota 1**:

El nombre de las bibliotecas de funciones suele indicarlo el proveedor de la biblioteca. Si miramos el manual de la función `pow` (usando [`man pow`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/pow) en Linux) podremos leer lo siguiente:

> ```
> NAME
>        pow, powf, powl - power functions
>
> SYNOPSIS
>        #include <math.h>
>
>        double pow(double x, double y);
>        float powf(float x, float y);
>        long double powl(long double x, long double y);
>
>        Link with -lm.
> ```

Donde puedes observar que te indica que debes enlazar (o compilar) con `-lm`.

Por pura casualidad el nombre de las funciones matemáticas es una única letra (`m`), pero por norma general suele ser un nombre más descriptivo y el nombre del archivo está precedido por `lib`.

Ejemplos:

- Funciones para manipular archivos PNG ([libpng 1.6](http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/libpng.html)):

  - Nombre: `png16`
  - Archivo: `libpng16.so`/`libpng16.a`
  - Enlazado: `-lpng16`
- Funciones para manipular archivos ZIP ([libzip](https://libzip.org/documentation/)):

  - Nombre: `zip`
  - Archivo: `libzip.so`
  - Enlazado: `-lzip`

---

**Nota 2**: (gracias [@Trauma](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/19610/trauma) por el apunte)

Por defecto, si existen versiones de enlazado compartido/dinámico (`.so`) y estático (`.a`), se usa el enlazado compartido (`libm.so`).

Se pueden forzar uno u otro tipo de enlazado con los parámetros `-static` y `-shared`.

Si usamos `-static`, la utilidad `ldd` (que imprime las dependencias de objetos compartidos), nos indicará que no es un ejecutable dinámico (que haga uso de objetos compartidos `.so`):

```
$ gcc -o pruebas pruebas.c -static -lm
$ ldd pruebas
    no es un ejecutable dinámico
```

Sin embargo, tanto si se usa `-shared` como si no, la salida de `ldd` nos indicará que hace uso de la biblioteca compartida `libm.so`:

```
$ gcc -o pruebas pruebas.c -shared -lm
$ ldd pruebas
        linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007fff979af000)
        libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f6f1a6c1000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f6f1a2d0000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f6f1ac61000)
$ gcc -o pruebas pruebas.c -lm
$ ldd pruebas
        linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffc0d580000)
        libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f18cd144000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f18ccd53000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f18cd6e4000)
```

Comment: Gracias (yo usu Ubuntu).

Comment: ¿Cada biblioteca tiene una letra, como puedo saber cual es la letra para cada una? Te pregunto esto en caso de que mas adelante en otros programas con otras bibliotecas me da el mismo error. Gracias.

Comment: +1 ... Solo por ponerme *puntilloso*, y aunque creo que al OP aun le falta un *ratito* para llegar a esto: o añades `-static` o cambias el nombre de la librería buscada a `libm.so` :-)

Comment: @Trauma , como siempre, muchísimas gracias por tus observaciones. Agradezco muchísimo las críticas constructivas, agregué más detalles en la **nota 2** ;) Plazamarco, he agregado más explicaciones respecto a tus dudas con el nombre en la **nota 1**.

Comment: Plazamarco, si mi respuesta te aclaró las dudas, haz el favor de marcarla como respuesta correcta pulsando en el tick que hay arriba a la izquierda de la respuesta. Si te quedó algo sin responder déjame un comentario para mejorar mi respuesta. Un saludo.